# Insert multiple SQL Queries while in PHP Loop

Tags: php, mysql, xpath, mysqli, foreach

I am getting data and while in a loop, trying to insert it into a mysql table. The first insert (of many at a time) works, but after the first entry, I get the error for every attempt thereafter in the script.

**Success:**

A new entry has been added with the `id` of 0.

**Error:**

mysqli::query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli (Which gets repeated several times, from several other query attempts.)

**Code:**

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($resultspage);
libxml_clear_errors();
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$data = array();
$rows = $xpath->query('//p[@class="row"]'); // get all rows
foreach($rows as $entries) { // loop each row
    $entry = array();
    $entry['title'] = $xpath->query('./span[@class="txt"]/span[@class="pl"]/a', $entries)->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $entry['link'] = 'http://' . $base_url . $xpath->query('./a[@class="i"]', $entries)->item(0)->getAttribute('href');
    $entry['price'] = $xpath->query('./span[@class="txt"]/span[@class="l2"]/span[1]', $entries)->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $location = $xpath->query('./span[@class="txt"]/span[@class="l2"]/span[2]', $entries)->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $loc = str_replace(array('(', ')'), '', $location);
    $entry['location'] = $loc;
    $entry['seller'] = $xpath->query('./span[@class="txt"]/span[@class="l2"]/a', $entries)->item(0)->nodeValue;
    //Get Address
    $url2 = $entry['link'];
    $page = file_get_contents($url2);
    $dom2 = new DOMDocument();
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $dom2->loadHTML($page);
    libxml_clear_errors();
    $xpath2 = new DOMXpath($dom2);
    $mapsection = $xpath2->query('//div[@class="mapAndAttrs"]'); 
    $entry['address'] = $xpath2->query('//div[@class="mapAndAttrs"]/div[@class="mapbox"]/div[@class="mapaddress"]')->item(0)->nodeValue;
    //End of Get Address
    $text_node = $xpath->query('./span[@class="txt"]/span[@class="l2"]/span[1]/following-sibling::text()[1]', $entries)->item(0)->nodeValue;
    // remove "/"" and "-""  | explode by space | filter space (now, its left by 2 values: bedroom and size)
    $text_node = array_filter(explode(' ', str_replace(array('/', '-'), '', $text_node)));
    $entry['bedrooms'] = array_shift($text_node); // bedroom
    $entry['dimensions'] = array_shift($text_node); // dimensions

    $data[] = $entry; // after gathering necessary items, assign inside

    //put data into db
    $q = "INSERT INTO `list` (`title`,`price`, `rooms`, `dimensions`, `location`, `address`, `seller`, `href`) VALUES ('".$entry['title']."','".$entry['price']."', '".$entry['bedrooms']."','".$entry['dimensions']."','".$entry['location']."','".$entry['address']."','".$entry['seller']."','".$entry['link']."')";
        if ( $mysqli->query($q) ) {
            echo "A new entry has been added with the `id` of {$mysqli->insert_id}.";
        } else {
            echo "There was a problem:<br />$q<br />{$mysqli->error}";
        }
    //Close it off
    $mysqli->close();
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
```

I would like somebody to assist me with understanding why all of these queries (after the first one) are unsuccessful. I am trying to get all queries to insert. Thanks for your time!

Comment: You're using mysqli, that's great! It would be even better, if you took advantage of prepared statements and bind your input values to parameters. You need to prepare your query only once before the loop.

Comment: Did I see right, you're closing your mysqli connection in the foreach loop. Do it outside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're closing your mysql connection a bit too early. It should be

```
$q = "INSERT INTO `list` (`title`,`price`, `rooms`, `dimensions`, `location`, `address`, `seller`, `href`) VALUES ('".$entry['title']."','".$entry['price']."', '".$entry['bedrooms']."','".$entry['dimensions']."','".$entry['location']."','".$entry['address']."','".$entry['seller']."','".$entry['link']."')";
    if ( $mysqli->query($q) ) {
        echo "A new entry has been added with the `id` of {$mysqli->insert_id}.";
    } else {
        echo "There was a problem:<br />$q<br />{$mysqli->error}";

   }
}
//Close it off
$mysqli->close();
echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
```

instead.

**Note**

Proper indenting of code is a great help to see such mistakes quickly.

Comment: That was a silly mistake. Thank you for catching that.